# Android Threads, Fragments and Adapters

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have created a custom adapter that inflates rows in a fragment. I would like to know how to put this in a thread.

In my fragment I have:

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
ListAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(courseId, context);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Every thing works this way but I have tried to put this in all four ways (AsyncTask, Java thread...) that Android offers for multithreading but the adapter won`t start that way. It just shows blank screen.

Can anyone help me how to put this in a separate thread?

Comment: Explain why you need to do this ? Read about Loaders and i think you're done!

Comment: @ikocijan: did you use AsyncTask, it's best one for doing this.

Comment: @Kitesurfer I need this because I want to start adapter in a new Thread and not in UI.

Comment: @Aerrow I tried to create a inner class in my fragment that extends AsyncTask but when I put this code in doInBackground the adapter does not start :/

Comment: Dont know why you need this still. Your concept has a problem i think or you're not understood what loaders do things like this already and have less problems than an AsyncTask.

Comment: @ikocijan: here is posted the sample code for your reference, kindly notice, and confirm, did you used in the same manner.

Comment: hm...did not try to put setAdapter method in onPostExecute. Will try this and report back. Thanks

Comment: @Aerrow - you answer worked. Would press this answer is usefull but I do not have enough reputation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference,

```
public class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Do your Background process Eg.. some Parsing whatever it's, then paste you adapter initialization code
            // Initialize your adapter as global
        CustomAdapter sampleAdapter = new CustomAdapter(CurrentActivity.this,
                        R.id.ImageView01, <Your Arraylist/Array>);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Here you set your adapter
            listView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
```